# xmlsec installation hangs in virtualenv environement

Tags: python-3.x, pip

when i try to install the package xmlsec in normal environment , it works fine and the the installation ends successfully by when i try to install the same package with the same pip3 version , it hangs:

```
 [root@5d01783a0d80 /]# pip3 install 'xmlsec==1.3.3'

Collecting xmlsec==1.3.3
Downloading http://prrepo.fr.net.intra/nexus/repository/pypi-software-fundation/packages/xmlsec/1.3.3/xmlsec-1.3.3.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: pkgconfig in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from  xmlsec==1.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml>=3.0 in /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages (from xmlsec==1.3.3)
Installing collected packages: xmlsec
Running setup.py install for xmlsec ... done
Successfully installed xmlsec-1.3.3
```

and in the virtual env

```
[root@5d01783a0d80 /]# cd /venv/awx/bin/
[root@5d01783a0d80 bin]# source activate
(awx) [root@5d01783a0d80 bin]# pip3 install 'xmlsec==1.3.3'
Looking in indexes: http://prrepo.fr.net.intra/nexus/repository/pypi-software-fundation/simple
Collecting xmlsec==1.3.3
Downloading http://prrepo.fr.net.intra/nexus/repository/pypi-software-fundation/packages   /xmlsec/1.3.3/xmlsec-1.3.3.tar.gz (29 kB)
```

it hangs for 10 min before and it end up with error looking in external repo not reachable for a dependency (lxml) that already exist locally.

Any idea please ?

Comment: How do you connect to the internal `pip` server? Do you need a proxy and/or a password?

Comment: The `Downloading` line seems to have whitespace after `/packages`; is that genuine, or a copy/paste error?